# Spring Boot version mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Hi I am developing `Spring Boot` application using version `2.5.4`. I am using one of our maven dependency which using `Spring Boot` Version `2.1.8.RELEASE` and I think because of this I am getting below error -

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.<init>()
```

Is there any way to avoid above error because I cannot change the version of our internal maven dependency.

Comment: If you can't change the internal 2.1.8 version then why not just use 2.1.8? Or are you relying on something specific to 2.5.4?

Comment: No. You have incompatible versions. Fix the dependency or downgrade your project. 

You can try playing around with excluding random things but likely your dependency would just break in weird ways at runtime.

Comment: Why is a _dependency_ using Spring Boot anyway - that seems all wrong…

Comment: Hi @B Can we use sleuth in